# Can Switch parental controls restrict shop access?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop

I'm looking into buying a Nintendo Switch for a kid. Is it possible to restrict access to the "shop" with parental controls? I don't want her to be able to download different free games and playing them, I only want to allow the games that I buy or download for her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the device will require you to sign in with your Nintendo account in order to gain access to purchases, and your kid may not have one. But you, as a parent, should.

Enabling the password restrictions can do the trick to block kids from using Nintendo Switch eShop. This restriction will appear when you access the Nintendo Switch eShop for the first time.

1. Go to the Home Screen of your Nintendo Switch.
2. Select **System Settings**.
3. Select **User**.
   Choose the desired user.
4. Scroll down and select **Nintendo eShop Settings**.
5. On the right pane, scroll down and look for **Password-Entry Settings**.
   Select the Change button.
6. Select **Enter** for all three items.
   If you want that the system will ask for your Nintendo eShop password when starting Nintendo eShop, using saved credit card, or when using PayPal, make sure select ENTER for all three items.
7. Select the **SAVE** button.

Comment: Thank you. So these steps would prevent the kid from downloading free games, since they wouldn't be able to start the eShop at all?

Comment: @Anna that's the idea, yes.